# How to write zend db transaction

Tags: php, zend-db

Is something wrong with my code. When i tried to execute it is not showing any error but it is not deleting from databse also.

```
function delete(){
try {
require('/inc/connect.php');
$publicId = $_POST["publicId"];
$select = $db->select()
    ->from('test', '*')
    ->where('test_public_id = ?', $publicId);
$checkedPublicId = $db->fetchRow($select);
if(!$checkedPublicId){
    throw new Exception("No tour with that id was found");
}
$testId = $checkedPublicId['test_id'];
$db->beginTransaction();
$sql1 = $db -> query ("DELETE FROM folder_test WHERE test_id ='.$testId.'");
$sql2 = $db -> query ("DELETE FROM image WHERE test_id ='.$testId.'");
$sql3 = $db -> query ("DELETE FROM test_shares WHERE test_id ='.$testId.'");
$sql4 = $db -> query ("DELETE FROM test_stats WHERE test_public_id ='.$publicId.'");
$sql5 = $db -> query ("DELETE FROM slides WHERE test_id ='.$testId.'");
$sql6 = $db -> query ("DELETE FROM test WHERE test_public_id ='.$publicId.'");
$query = $db->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    throw new Exception($e);
}
}
```

Comment: I think that beginTransaction should be called before try.

Comment: when i write beginTransaction before try getting Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object

Comment: Try move `$db->beginTransaction();` and all lines above outside of catch.

Comment: Btw, isn't a bug here `test_id ='.$testId.'"`?

Comment: i didn't get you. Where you are pointed the bug?

Comment: =".$publicId instead of ='.$publicId.'"

Comment: There's no reason for the transaction to be started outside of the try. It's the subsequent query() calls that would throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are broken.

```
$sql1 = $db -> query ('DELETE FROM folder_test WHERE test_id ='.$testId);
$sql2 = $db -> query ('DELETE FROM image WHERE test_id ='.$testId);
$sql3 = $db -> query ('DELETE FROM test_shares WHERE test_id ='.$testId);
$sql4 = $db -> query ('DELETE FROM test_stats WHERE test_public_id ='. $db -> quote($publicId));
$sql5 = $db -> query ('DELETE FROM slides WHERE test_id ='.$testId);
$sql6 = $db -> query ('DELETE FROM test WHERE test_public_id ='. $db -> quote($publicId));
```

Comment: Where $testId is only intergers and $pulicId is mixup of characters and numbers.

Comment: Updated it for you :-) Do note that it's not injection-proof - make sure not to use $_GET or $_POST as $publicId.

Comment: the thing is i am getting public id from another page using $_POST method